# Flexbox item vertically centered while fixing another item to bottom left corner

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I fix the `meta` class to the bottom left corner of the flex container while keeping the heading element `h1` vertically centered?

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <div class="meta">intro</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it out of flow and position it relatively to the container.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.meta {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <div class="meta">intro</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Switch to `flex-direction: column`
- Apply `justify-content: space-between`
- Insert an invisible "spacer" item to balance out both ends

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.invisible { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="invisible">intro</div>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <div class="meta">intro</div>
</div>
```

Note that flex alignment properties work by distributing available space in the container. This means that `justify-content: space-between` can precisely center the middle item (`h1`) only if both adjacent items are equal height. For more details see Box #71 [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276).

Comment: A less obtrusive way to balance could be choosing a `line-height` or `height` for `.meta` and inserting a `.container::before` pseudo-element with the same value.

Comment: @Oriol, yes, much cleaner. And solves the problem with semantics. Thanks.